# Copy row with account_id=account_id1?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

```
insert into user 
    (account_id, name, e_mail_addr)
select account_id, name, e_mail_addr
from user
where account_id='1';
```

How to copy row with id = id +1 and loop 100 times. It mean it will create 100 row with id from 2 to 100. 
I using this in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

SQL procedure:

```
drop procedure if exists user_clone;
delimiter #

create procedure user_clone()
begin

    declare u_max int unsigned default 100;
    declare u_counter int unsigned default 0;

    start transaction;
    while u_counter < u_max do
        INSERT INTO (name, e_mail_addr)
            SELECT name, e_mail_addr
            FROM user 
            WHERE account_id = 1;

        set u_counter=u_counter+1;
    end while;
    commit;
end #

delimiter ;

call user_clone();
drop procedure user_clone;
```